Comparative Political Economy vs. Comparative Political Economics
When talking about economy vs. economics, we can find explanation:

Economy refers to the system of production, distribution, and consumption of goods and services, while economics is the academic discipline that studies the principles and theories behind economic activities.

So, if the term economics should be used to refer to an academic discipline, why is the term economy used in the name of an academic course in comparative political economy?

Where and by whom? Please cite your sources.

@Lambie, for instance, by Google Books Ngram Viewer: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Comparative+Political+Economics%2C+Comparative+Political+Economy. Besides that, the query «"Comparative Political Economy"» returns ca. 615K, while «"Comparative Political Economics"» — provides just 20K.

Try googling "political economy".

@Mike Please note that you have misread the Google results. From Google ""Comparative Political Economy" - In order to show you the most relevant results, we have omitted some entries very similar to the 125 already displayed.
If you like, you can repeat the search with the omitted results included. --
"Comparative Political Economics" - In order to show you the most relevant results, we have omitted some entries very similar to the 70 already displayed.
If you like, you can repeat the search with the omitted results included."

@Greybeard, how should I run the query with the omitted results included?

The discipline is political economy: https://www.investopedia.com/terms/p/political-economy.asp#:~:text=Political%20economy%20is%20an%20interdisciplinary,work%20in%20the%20real%20world.

@Mike The words "repeat the search with the omitted results included" are a hyperlink.

@Greybeard, are you sure? I don't see any hyperlink.

@Mike I am absolutely certain: See bottom of the page at https://www.google.com/search?q="Comparative+Political+Economy"&num=10&client=opera&hs=Z3F&sca_esv=28f8fab5923385a6&ei=DvgOZ7rOFtHmxc8PuZbqoAE&start=120&sa=N&sstk=Aagrsugpo6sq7mwSDw-8j7UE1NQgs_GjtmQdV9djg109awVCgKqK3S-rn4OuSqyLgX8nFw6qbAhJyIZmjBuTOYBeqyTa70hTViDWmL7mHb8NAl8B5x1lZGh6XE2Zn0h6mKXs&ved=2ahUKEwi6jaXEwpGJAxVRc_EDHTmLGhQ4WhDy0wN6BAgGEBU&biw=1860&bih=937&dpr=1.38

I think the term "comparative political economy" refers to a political science subfield that studies and compares different political economies. It's an interdisciplinary field that's related to economics, but it's not studying economics itself.
